# Batch : Renaming a folder in 'program files'

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I need to write a batch to rename a folder in `Program Files`.

I'm able to do it through the Explorer, so I guess I have all required rights.

But when I write something like this in a command line :

```
move "C:\Program Files\Ceebot4\train" train_old
```

I get the following error : `Access denied.`

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: I think this is more of a serverfault question, even with the 'batch' bit attached.

Comment: @Adriano: Or superuser, but this is one of those crossover things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A batch file runs in MS-Dos mode and so is subject to different access rights to Windows Explorer. Try running your batch file or Dos prompt as an administrator should work

Comment: Is there an equivalent of sudo in DOS ?

Comment: I just tried this locally. Running as admin works, not running as admin causes it to fail

Comment: yes have a look at the runas command or add the batch file to your desktop/start menu, set it to always run as administrator

Comment: that's it : I'm now launching cmd.exe with administrator rights and can call move (with the correct syntax as mentionned by Anders Abel) and it works !

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to move the contents to a directory named `train_old` right under the directory where you currently are when executing the command. If you want to rename the directory in current place you will have to use:

```
move "C:\Program Files\Ceebot4\train" "C:\Program Files\Ceebot4\train_old"
```

Comment: I'd use %PROGRAMFILES% too, just to get used to it.

Comment: @Jérôme: If you've tried what Anders said and you get access denied, there's a different problem (something in the way)?

Comment: @Anders: He'll need to be careful it doesn't already exist, or he'll end up with a `C:\Program Files\Ceebot4\train_old\train` directory!

Answer (score 0):

`move` moves things, so either do what Anders said (giving the full path in both places; but be careful the target name doesn't already exist), or use `ren` instead:

```
ren "C:\Program Files\Ceebot4\train" train_old
```